# Como inserir um valor em uma copia da tabela?

Tags: java, sql-server

Estou realizando uma transferência da tabela "`Histo_Ficha_Controle`" para "`Cad_Espec_Teste`". As duas tabelas contém os mesmos campos para receber as informações. Ao realizar a copia de uma tabela para outra, gostaria de saber se é possível fazer uma inserção de valor em uma das colunas.

```
insira o código aqui
String query1 = "INSERT INTO Cad_Espec_Teste (ORDEM,ESP_LINHA ,ESP_MATERIAL ,ESP_TESTE ,ESP_EQUIPAMENTO ,MINIMO ,MAXIMO ,UNID_MEDIDA ,TEXTO ,REFERENCIA ,FREQUENCIA ,"
                    + "UNID_FREQUENCIA,PRODUTO ,ORIGEM ,TIPO_ESPEC ,ESPEC_COMPLETO ,FREQ_COMPLETO ,LAB ,COMPLEMENTO,RESPONSAVEL_ALTER,PENDENCIA_ALTER ,DATA_ALTER,OBSERVACAO_ALTER,"
                    + "DATE_VALIDE_ALTER,ALTER_IDENTIFICACAO) SELECT ORDEM,HISTO_LINHA,HISTO_MATERIAL,HISTO_TESTE,HISTO_EQUIPAMENTO,HISTO_MINIMO,HISTO_MAXIMO,"
                    + "HISTO_UNID_MEDIDA,HISTO_TEXTO,HISTO_REFERENCIA,HISTO_FREQUENCIA,HISTO_UNID_FREQUENCIA,HISTO_PRODUTO,HISTO_ORIGEM,HISTO_TIPO_ESPEC,HISTO_ESPEC_COMPLEMENTO,"
                    + "HISTO_FREQ_COMPLETO,HISTO_LAB,HISTO_COMPLEMENTO,HISTO_RESPONSAVEL,HISTO_PENDENCIA,HISTO_DATA_HISTO,HISTO_OBSERVACAO,HISTO_DATE_VALID,"
                    + "ALTER_IDENTIFICACAO FROM Histo_Ficha_Controle WHERE HISTO_MATERIAL='" + txt_perfil.getText() + "' and HISTO_DATA_HISTO='"+txt_data.getText()+"'";
```

Essa é a String que estou utilizando para fazer a transferência de uma `jtable` para outra e gostaria de inserir o seguinte valor: "Troca de Versão" na coluna "PENDENCIA_ALTER"

Comment: Sua duvida continua obscura. Você não fornece dados suficientes para analise do que é preciso saber, essa string não colabora em praticamente nada no entendimento do problema. Forneça um código mais relevante para que seja possível entender melhor o problema

Comment: E você não precisa copiar uma tabela inteira para outra, no caso de `JTable`, se quer os mesmos dados em duas tabelas diferentes, para replicar ou utilizar o mesmo `TableModel` para as duas.

Comment: Como pode ver eu tenho 2 tabelas, uma chama Histo_Ficha_Controle  que no caso é minha tabela de Histórico e a outra e Cad_Espec_Teste .. quando faço uma alteração em informações da tabela Cad_Espec_Teste, eu salvo uma cópia na Histórico.. nesse caso estou trazendo uma versão antiga para substituir a atual e para isso estou colocando um status em pendencia para ser visualizado.

Comment: Entao seria interessante adicionar essa explicação na pergunta tambem, pois deu pra entender melhor o problema através dela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu `select` basta você pode escrever 1 texto e ele será replicado em todas linhas, fiz sem ser atribuindo 1 valor para string e identado para facilitar a visualização

```
INSERT INTO Cad_Espec_Teste 
    (ORDEM,ESP_LINHA ,ESP_MATERIAL ,ESP_TESTE ,ESP_EQUIPAMENTO ,MINIMO ,MAXIMO ,UNID_MEDIDA ,TEXTO ,REFERENCIA ,FREQUENCIA
    UNID_FREQUENCIA,PRODUTO ,ORIGEM ,TIPO_ESPEC ,ESPEC_COMPLETO ,FREQ_COMPLETO ,LAB ,COMPLEMENTO,RESPONSAVEL_ALTER,PENDENCIA_ALTER ,DATA_ALTER,OBSERVACAO_ALTER
    DATE_VALIDE_ALTER,ALTER_IDENTIFICACAO) 
SELECT 
    ORDEM,HISTO_LINHA,
    HISTO_MATERIAL,
    HISTO_TESTE,
    HISTO_EQUIPAMENTO,
    HISTO_MINIMO,
    HISTO_MAXIMO
    HISTO_UNID_MEDIDA,
    HISTO_TEXTO,
    HISTO_REFERENCIA,
    HISTO_FREQUENCIA,
    HISTO_UNID_FREQUENCIA,
    HISTO_PRODUTO,
    HISTO_ORIGEM,
    HISTO_TIPO_ESPEC,
    HISTO_ESPEC_COMPLEMENTO
    HISTO_FREQ_COMPLETO,
    HISTO_LAB,
    HISTO_COMPLEMENTO,
    HISTO_RESPONSAVEL,
    'Troca de Versão', -- aqui o texto
    HISTO_DATA_HISTO,
    HISTO_OBSERVACAO,
    HISTO_DATE_VALID
    ALTER_IDENTIFICACAO 
FROM Histo_Ficha_Controle 
WHERE HISTO_MATERIAL= x and HISTO_DATA_HISTO= y
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pelas dica e solução @Barbetta, resolveu meu problema!

Comment: @GabrielBispo Disponha. Não se esqueça de aceitar a resposta - https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079